# Formula to project a line onto a plane

Tags: python, math, 3d, projection

I have a vector and project it onto a plane. I tried to compute the projection but I found the formula seems not correct.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

# n is the normalized normal of the plane and v is the vector
n = np.array([0.6,  0.3, -0.7])
v = np.array([-415, 212, 180])

p =  v - np.dot(v, n) / (np.linalg.norm(n)**2) * n
# array([-216.23404255,  311.38297872,  -51.89361702])

cross_product = np.cross(p, n)
# array([202.4, 182.5, 251.7])
```

"
If the formula works, the projection "p" on the plane should be perpendicular to normal "n"
and the np.cross() result should be (0,0,0). However, as the above shows, the cross result is ([202.4, 182.5, 251.7]).

I don't know why this formula doesn't work here. Anyone can help me figure it out?

Comment: The dot product of orthogonal vectors is zero, the cross product is a third orthogonal vector.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so what you are doing is you using the 'projection' *p* to calculate the cross product when instead you need to use the projected vector to get the cross product you can do it by

```
projected_vector = v - p
```

and then use *projected_vector* to calculate the cross product:

```
cross_product = np.cross(projected_vector, n)
```

Detailed Explanation to the subtraction:
When you compute the projection you actually find the the component of the vector v that is in the direction of the normal to the plane, obtain the component of v that is in the plane, you subtract this projection from the original vector.
If you are directly use the p vector (projection) you are only using the projected component and ignoring the component that is in the plane.